# Modular arithmetic with a gigantic exponent (ie. $2^{2^{403}} \equiv x$ (mod $23$))

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, congruences

Suppose I want to find $2^{2^{403}} \equiv x$ (mod $23$). Now I know by Fermat's Little Theorem that $2^{22} \equiv 1 \space (\mod 23)$ and I know how to show that $2^{403} \equiv 8 \space (\mod 22)$. But I don't know how to put these two together to solve the congruence, or if I'm missing some crucial simplification step or theorem. I can't even use WolframAlpha because the number is too big.

My question is: How do you solve $2^{2^{403}} \equiv x$ (mod $23$)?

Comment: If $2^{403} \equiv 8 \pmod{22}$, then $2^{403} = 22k + 8$ for some integer $k$. So, $2^{2^{403}} \equiv 2^{22k + 8} \equiv (2^{22})^k \cdot 2^{8} \pmod{23}$. Does this lead you somewhere?

Comment: You've already done all the hard work.

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza that worked thanks. If you wanna put that in an answer i'll mark it as the answer

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It, or parts of it, have turned up a lot recently.

Comment: @lulu It is a question from a university math course